# JSON format is not recognized when I create an array with more than one element

Tags: arrays, json, parsing

I want to create a JSON array which includes two elements.
I wrote the following code:

```
  var myArray2 = [
      {
        "nome": "Aldo Maria",
        "indirizzo": "Viale Europa 1",
        "telefono": "3397889034"
      },
      {
        nome: "Maria13",
        indirizzo: "Viale Europa 1",
        telefono: "3397889034"
      }
    ];
```

I'm trying to parse it by using the Chrome extension Json Viewer Awesome but I get the error

> Failed to parse invalid JSON format

On the other hand, I don't get this error while inserting a single element in the array, as in the snippet below:

```
{
    "myArray2": [
        {
            "message": "Welcome to Awesome JSON Viewer.",
            "status_code": 200
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: `myArray2` is a JavaScript array, and it is unclear how you take that array and parse it with that extension you mention. To get a JSON representation of that array, use `JSON.stringify(myArray2)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes because your keys doesn't contains `double quotes ("")` for the part of json. 
The valid JSON would be

> In JSON, keys must be strings, written with double quotes.

```
[{
        "nome": "Aldo Maria",
        "indirizzo": "Viale Europa 1",
        "telefono": "3397889034"
    },
    {
        "nome": " Maria13",
        "indirizzo": "Viale Europa 1",
        "telefono": "3397889034"
    }
]
```

> In JavaScript, keys can be strings, numbers, or identifier names.See example

```
{ name:"John" }
```

For reference look

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON)