# array of object string convert to array of object only javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have a string that contains an array of object `'[{letter: a, number: 1}, {letter: b, number: 2}]'` I'm trying to make it literally a array of object using `JSON.parse()` but I'm getting an error saying

```
`SyntaxError: Unexpected token l in JSON at position 2`
```

My code

```
let a = '[{letter: \'a\', number: 1}, {letter: \'b\', number: 2}]'

let b = JSON.parse(a)

console.log(b)
```

I can't even use `a.split(',')` because I have a `,` inside the object

my expected output was

```
[{letter: 'a', number: 1}, {letter: 'b', number: 2}]
```

how can I fix it?

Comment: This is not valid JSON. You need to use double quotes, not single quotes. And you also need double quotes around the keys.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56396302/7849549 -see this

Comment: The contents of `a` is not valid JSON (and thus cannot be parsed as such). You can use `eval` and it will return the expected array. I would however advice against `eval`, and instead implore you to change the format of your data

Comment: JSON is not JS. It is really more strict.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In JSON keys must be strings, so you have to reformat your JSON string like this:

```
[{"letter": "a", "number": 1}, {"letter": "b", number: 2}]
```

More info, see [this article](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_objects.asp)

Comment: "*In JSON keys must be strings*" they *are* strings. But you need double quotes around them because that's what the specs say.